# Software install permission to a user in whole network

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I need to give a user the right to install the software as an administrator in whole network computers but they don't want him to have access to anything else on the domain. I assuming GPO settings are available in windows servers but I am not sure. Can someone point me in the right direction and give me the exact solution on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Restricted Groups** from the GPO which will make your user a **local administrator** on devices.